# Python Selenium selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium

I recently started learning automation. I am trying to automate Finnair.com site.  But having the following issue in my code. It works until trying clicking the "Helsinki" item.

**Error:**

> ```sh
> check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document Traceback (most recent call last): line 35, in <module>
> if city.text == "Helsinki (HEL)": line 76, in text
> return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value'] Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
> return self._parent.execute(command, params)   line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response) line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)--- Error
> ```

**My code:**

```py
driver.get("https://www.finnair.com/us-en")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn rounded pr-large-x tr-small')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
traveltype = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.mr-xxsmall-l")
traveltype[1].click()  #Oneway according to the index  to change i can say 0
print(len(traveltype))
#Selecting Orgin and Destination Locations
driver.find_element_by_class_name("bw-origin").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#origin-input").send_keys("HEL")
time.sleep(5)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Helsinki (HEL)']").click()
orgin = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ts-xsmall")
time.sleep(5)
for city in orgin:
    if city.text == "Helsinki (HEL)":
        city.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'bw-destination')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Type and select destination')]").send_keys("TLL")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Tallinn (TLL)']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `break` after you click the element. Once you have found and clicked the match, the origin list ("bw-origin") is no longer there. This is what causes the `StaleElementReferenceException`. Also no need to loop through the whole list either once you found the match.

```
for city in orgin:
    if city.text == "Helsinki (HEL)":
        city.click()
        break
```

Side note - consider using more `WebDriverWait`s and less `time.sleep`.